# Can there be abstract method in a main class?

Tags: java

```
/**
 * Tests the BankAccount class and their subclasses
 * @author Saul
 *
 */
public class AccountTester 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SavingsAccount sa = new SavingsAccount(2,2000);
        CheckingAccount ca = new CheckingAccount(0);
        TimeDepositAccount hp = new TimeDepositAccount(10,3,15,5);
        test(sa);
        test(ca);
        test(hp);
    }
    
    public static void test(BankAccount account)
       {
            account.deposit(400);
            account.deposit(2000);
            account.withdraw(100);
            account.deposit(200);
            account.withdraw(300);
          System.out.println(account.getClass() + " before endOfMonth, the balance is: $" + account.getBalance());
          
          account.endOfMonth();
          System.out.println(account.getClass() + " after endOfMonth, the balance is: $" + account.getBalance());
       }
}
```

Here is my code, and I was wondering if the class can be abstract if there is a main method and also a normal method with an abstract method inside. Would this class called an abstract class?  The abstract method is endOfMonth()

Comment: Why not just test it?

Comment: Have you *tried* making the class `abstract`?

Comment: I have a Super class that is abstract but I just don't know if this is abstract when it is no extended

Comment: @Saul Any class can be marked as `abstract`. What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: Yes there can.  Indeed, provided that you don't need to create an instance of the "main" class, that abstract method doesn't need a concrete method in a subclass.  (But the method would be pointless ...)

Comment: I just tested and added 'abstract' into the  'public class AccountTester' and it worked out fine. Would this class be abstract?

Comment: Yes.  The class must be declared as abstract if it has abstract methods.  Java 101 stuff.  (Why are you asking this?  Why would you want / need your "main" class to be abstract / have abstract methods?  What does it achieve?  Is this just idle curiosity?  Seriously, you won't get + votes for asking "I'm just curious" questions that could be answered with some simple tests and/or reading a tutorial.)

Comment: I am really sorry, I was just really confused with abstract methods, I am also new to Java.

Comment: They are simple.  A method is abstract if you declare it with the `abstract` modifier.  The consequence is that you cannot create an instance of that class.  You can (but you don't have to) create another class that extends your abstract class.  If *that* class is not also declared as abstract you can create an instance from it.  But it must also implement all of the methods that were declared as abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is my code, and I was wondering if the class can be abstract if there is a main method and also a normal method with an abstract method inside.

You cannot put a method inside a method in java, so trivially: No, you can't do that.

> Would this class called an abstract class?

You can't put abstract methods in a class unless that class is also tagged `abstract`, so, trivially, yes, of course it would.

You should be trying these things instead of asking more questions on SO, you'll learn much faster that way. Stick a method in a method and attempt to compile it. Stick an abstract method in a class and compile it - you'll find the compiler tells you that your code will not compile as abstract methods are not allowed in a non-abstract class.

> Can there be abstract method in a main class?

The concept 'main class' isn't a thing. You can have a class that so happens to have a method named `main`, marked `static`, with a return type of `void` and a single parameter of type `String[]`, and such a class can be executed from the command line.

Given that the `main` method is `static`, it opted out entirely of all inheritance properties of that class: You can put static methods in an abstract class or a not-abstract one, doesn't matter and has no bearing.

Also, static methods 'do not do' inheritance, and `abstract` only makes sense in terms of what that means for inheritance; hence, a `static abstract` method does not make sense and won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

Judging by the wording of your question, you mean by "main class" a class with a `public static void main(String[])` method.

The method is `static`, so it is not subject to inheritance. Whether the class is marked `abstract`, is not relevant at all. The same goes for `interface`, `enum` and `record`.